# Windows phone - C# - Retrieving contact email

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, email, windows-phone-8, contacts

In my application I have a button which you can click on to send an email with certain contents. However I would like to know how to choose an email contact from the phones contacts, through some sort of contact-picker?

Is there any in-built contact-picker which I could use?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [EmailAddressChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394016%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
EmailAddressChooserTask eact = new EmailAddressChooserTask();
eact.Completed += eact_Completed;
eact.Show();

void eact_Completed(object sender, EmailResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    { 
       string selectedEmail = e.Email;
    }
    else
    {
       //nothing chosen
    }      
}
```

Comment: Just a quick follow up, is there any similar device for tweeting a certain message?

Comment: Yup, see the [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class :)